# Write a pass to replace all llvm instructions

Tags: c++11, llvm

I'm trying to write an llvm pass to replace all BinaryOperator instructions by a multiplication, the problem is that only the 1st instruction is replaced:

```
virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &F) {
  for (auto &B : F) {
     for (BasicBlock::iterator DI = B.begin(); DI != B.end(); ) {
      Instruction *Inst = DI++;

      if (auto *op = dyn_cast<BinaryOperator>(&*Inst)) {
        // Insert at the point where the instruction `op` appears.
        IRBuilder<> builder(op);

        // Make a multiply with the same operands as `op`.
        Value *lhs = op->getOperand(0);
        Value *rhs = op->getOperand(1);
        Value *mul = builder.CreateMul(lhs, rhs);

        // Everywhere the old instruction was used as an operand, use our
        // new multiply instruction instead.
        for (auto &U : op->uses()) {
          User *user = U.getUser();  // A User is anything with operands.
          user->setOperand(U.getOperandNo(), mul);
        }


        // We modified the code.
        return true;
      }


    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: You're returning true after making the first change. Keep a flag and return it at the end, after both loops.

Comment: Thank you very much  Ismail Badawi I tried that and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does the job:

```
 for (BasicBlock::iterator DI = B.begin(); DI != B.end(); ) {

  Instruction *Inst = DI++;

  if (auto *op = dyn_cast<BinaryOperator>(&*Inst)) {
    // Insert at the point where the instruction `op` appears.
    IRBuilder<> builder(op);

    // Make a multiply with the same operands as `op`.
    Value *lhs = op->getOperand(0);
    Value *rhs = op->getOperand(1);
    Value *mul = builder.CreateMul(lhs, rhs);

    // Everywhere the old instruction was used as an operand, use our
    // new multiply instruction instead.
    for (auto &U : op->uses()) {
      User *user = U.getUser();  // A User is anything with operands.
      user->setOperand(U.getOperandNo(), mul);
    }

    // We modified the code.

  }

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &F) {
  bool bModified = false;
 for (auto &B : F) {
  for (BasicBlock::iterator DI = B.begin(); DI != B.end(); ) {
   Instruction *Inst = DI++;

   if (auto *op = dyn_cast<BinaryOperator>(&*Inst)) {
    // Insert at the point where the instruction `op` appears.
    IRBuilder<> builder(op);

    // Make a multiply with the same operands as `op`.
    Value *lhs = op->getOperand(0);
    Value *rhs = op->getOperand(1);
    Value *mul = builder.CreateMul(lhs, rhs);

    // Everywhere the old instruction was used as an operand, use our
    // new multiply instruction instead.
    for (auto &U : op->uses()) {
      User *user = U.getUser();  // A User is anything with operands.
      user->setOperand(U.getOperandNo(), mul);
     }

    // We modified the code.
    bModified |= true;
    }
   }
 }
 return bModified;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very Much C. Patel I returned  after both loops and it works now.

Comment: @YasserNezzari If this is an answer for you question, please mark it so.